# Use of undeclared type "NSManagedObjectModel"

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsmanagedobjectmodel

I am trying to translate my code from Objective-C to Swift but for `NSManagedObjectModel` I get this error:

> Use of undeclared type NSManagedObjectModel.

The code in Objective-C:

```
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;       
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

I translated to Swift:

```
var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel?
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext?
var persistentStoreCoordinator:  NSPersistentStoreCoordinator?
```

Is it right?

Comment: import CoreData

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing the import for CoreData. Put this in the top of your file to the other `import` statements:

```
import CoreData
```